# Seeding rand() in C with Specified Values

Tags: c, random-seed, seeding

If you wanted a random number generator to use ints 2,5,7,4 and you seed your generator with

```
srand(2,5,7,4)

printf("%d \n",rand())
```

Is this flawed in accomplishing that?

Comment: Seems like you're expecting the numbers generated from a specified array, isn't it?

Comment: `srand` only takes one argument, so that won’t work. Did your compiler give a warning about that? You might need to enable more warnings.

Comment: True @Ry-, GDB compiler throws an error directly that too many arguments are supplied.

Comment: @LinuX Man so I can create an array first and use the single call to that arr as the argument for srand?

Comment: if seed is constant int  ,it will produce the same number instead of new random number. If you are curious about how it works you can check this site. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to print a value from a given array randomly on each execution, you may consider using the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    srand ( time(NULL) ); // accepts one argument only

    int myArray[4] = { 2,5,7,4 }; // array required
    int randomIndex = rand() % 4; // limiting randomness
    int randomValue = myArray[randomIndex]; // choosing one of the random numbers

    printf("Random value from array: %d\n", randomValue); // simply prints
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is insightful. If I wanted to go further and print some random numbers the same amount of times as the int argument stored as *int I could even add that as well to the printf statement with a simple for loop.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how it works. An PRNG uses an algorithm to generate a sequence of numbers with random like behaviour. For a given seed, a given sequence of numbers will be generated, what those number are is entirely up to the algorithm used.

to get a random number for a list, you will need something like:

```
n = list[rand() % (sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0])];
```